# ckeditor onChange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

i am using ckeditor,now i want to translate the content in onChange event using google translation api[is there any other methods ?]

so i think that i need the onChange event of ckeditor ,

i tried this but not working...

```
$('.CKeditor').ckeditor();
for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('change', function() {alert('text changed!');});
}
```

is there any possibilities ?

***Note :: My Requirment is a text box that can enter arabic text[but i need a rich text editor] other methods are welcome!***

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think `onchange` is the event you want here. I could imagine it would be very annoying translating text as it's being typed. How do you know when a word is finished being typed? How do you know the full structure of the sentence to know exactly the tense of the word to translate. A better approach in my opinion would be to create a toolbar button plugin which would translate the text after it has been typed in to the editor.

Comment: thanks for the comment,actually my requirement is make a rich text box  with input language to arabic.anyway ?

Comment: there is a way i can calcualte the word through a `space`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues with the change event, try something like:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[name].on("instanceReady", function(){                    
this.document.on("keyup", function(){
    t.text(CKEDITOR.instances[name].getData());
    t.trigger("change");
});
});
```

Comment: What is the `t` variable?